# Protractor: getText() getAttribute('value') or getAttribute('innterHTML') none of them working

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to retrieve text 'GHYTH68JH' from the td object.

The way I am doing it is:

```
Then(/^I should be able to download the PDF file '(.*)'$/, function (reportType, done) {
    let obj = element(by.xpath("//td[2][text()='"+reportType+"']/../td[3]")).getText()
               .then(function (text){
               console.log(text);
               done;
           });
});
```

And getting result=undefined

I have tried .getAttribute('value') and .getAttribute('innerHTML') and getting same result.

The HTML for the piece of code is:

```
<tbody>
   <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="val in vm.Cases">
    <td class="ng-binding" data-th="Date">26/05/2017</td>
    <td class="ng-binding" data-th="Type">Report</td>
    <td class="ng-binding" data-th="Order #">GHYTH68JH</td>
    <td class="ng-binding" data-th="Ref"> </td>
    <td class="ng-scope" ng-if="val.RStatus=='Available'">
      <div class="download_button">
        <span ng-click="vm.download(val.InciId,val.ONum)">Download</span>
     </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

---

Package:

```
"protractor": "5.1.2",
"cucumber": "2.3.1",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "3.1.2",
"chai": "3.5.0",
"chai-as-promised": "6.0.0",
"cucumber-html-reporter": "2.0.0",
"grunt-protractor-runner": "5.0.0",
"grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
```

Please do not mark this question as duplicate as I have already tried searching for a solution and found a few and hence used them in my code snippet, however, I am not able to get the text from the object.

Feel free to link this question with existing similar.

Comment: What are you passing for `reportType`?

Comment: passing 'Report' as string to the reportType (Type object) argument as the Order# need to be related to Report type

Comment: read it as "//td[2][text()='Report']/../td[3]"

Comment: @Phil any suggestions?